# How do I divide a value with a string condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Quantity (integer) field and a Name (string) field.  How do I divide only Product C by three to return a New Quantity value? I'm getting tripped up with errors for mixing string and integer types with everything I've tried.

```
Name        Quantity   New Quantity
Product A      5              5
Product B     35             35
Product C     27              9
```

Here's the query I'm working with:

```
SELECT 
      chg.name
      , sim.Description      
      , loc.location_name
      , Service_Date = CONVERT(DATE, chg.begin_date_of_service)
      , sim.Service_Type
      , sim.Visit_Type
      , sim.Contraceptive_Type
      , sim.Lab_Type
      , sim.Immunization_Type
      , chg.quantity

FROM 
      charges chg 
      INNER JOIN PPMNS_Service_Item_Info sim ON chg.name = sim.name
            AND chg.begin_date_of_service BETWEEN sim.SIM_Eff_Date AND sim.SIM_Exp_Date
            AND ((chg.begin_date_of_service BETWEEN   sim.Billing_NDC_Eff_Date AND sim.Billing_NDC_Exp_Date) OR sim.Billing_NDC_Eff_Date = '')
      INNER JOIN location_mstr loc ON chg.location_id = loc.location_id
WHERE 
      chg.link_id IS NULL
      AND sim.Visit_Rank < 50
```

Comment: post your attempt as well. also explain why you want to divide only product c's quantity.

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far? You need to show what you have tried in order to get us to help you out, were not just a magical code machine here, you need to show your efforts and where your errors/issues are when you post.

Comment: if [Name] = 'Product A' THEN div([quantity],3)
else [quantity]
END

Comment: Hi Gabriel - I've tried something like the above example - I just don't know where to go from there. I hope that's helpful. Product C needs to be divided by three as it's a medication with a set quantity of 3 in the database but needs to be counted as one product dispensed.

Answer (score 0):

This actually isn't to terribly hard to do. Judging from your tags you are more than likely doing this in a SQL program, such as Razor or anything of that sort.

```
Select Quantity, (Quantity / 3)
From table
where name = "PRODUCT C"
```

That should be all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking a look, NWcic!  I added my query above, would you know how I'd incorporate your language into it?

Comment: Goordon Linoff has the right idea on how to incorporate it, just below me here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would use a `case` statement:

```
select . . .
       (case when name = 'PRODUCT C' then chg.quantity / 3 else chg.quantity
        end) as quantity
. . .
```

Note that SQL Server does integer division if both operands are integers.  If `quantity` is an integer and you want decimal places, then you can divide by `3.0` instead of `3`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following  column to the  Select statement if you are using SQL Server 2012 or later versions

**iif(name='PRODUCT C',Quantity/3.0,Quantity) newQuantity**